# Display In stock available variations in WooCommerce single product short description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product-variations

I have variable products with many variations where only a few items are actually In Stock while the majority of other variations are ''available on backorder''

I would like to be able to display a quick list of ONLY the items that are IN STOCK in the short product description of each product page so the customer doesn't have to try all variations one-by-one to finally find out which ones are in stock.

I've searched for plugins or code that can do this but did not find anything.

The [closest code I found](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-display-variations-name-stock-shop-page/) is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bb_echo_stock_variations_loop' );
function bb_echo_stock_variations_loop(){
    global $product;

    if ( $product->get_type() == 'variable' ) {
        foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $key ) {
            $attr_string = array();

            foreach ( $key['attributes'] as $attr_name => $attr_value ) {
                $attr_string[] = $attr_value;
            }

            if ( $key['max_qty'] > 0 ) { 
              echo '<br/>' . implode( ', ', $attr_string ) . ': ' . $key['max_qty'] . ' in stock'; 
            } else { 
              echo '<br/>' . implode(', ', $attr_string ) . ': out of stock'; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it displays "In stock" available variations on the SHOP page and I want it to be displayed on the single product short description.

How can I display "In stock" available variations in single product short description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display in stock variations list in product single pages on short description, use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'display_in_stock_variations_to_short_description' );
function display_in_stock_variations_to_short_description( $excerpt ){
    global $product;

    if ( ! is_product() || empty($product) || ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) 
        return $excerpt;

    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        // Loop through visible children
        foreach( $product->get_children() as $variation_id ) {
            $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );

            // Hide out of stock variations if 'Hide out of stock items from the catalog' is checked.
            if ( ! $variation || ! $variation->exists() || ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items' ) && ! $variation->is_in_stock() ) ) {
                continue;
            }

            // Filter 'woocommerce_hide_invisible_variations' to optionally hide invisible variations (disabled variations and variations with empty price).
            if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_hide_invisible_variations', true, $product->get_id(), $variation ) && ! $variation->variation_is_visible() ) {
                continue;
            }

            $max_qty    = 0 < $variation->get_max_purchase_quantity() ? $variation->get_max_purchase_quantity() : $variation->get_stock_quantity();
            $term_names = []; // Initializing

            // Loop through variation attributes for current varation
            foreach ( $variation->get_variation_attributes() as $attribute => $term_slug ) {
                // Set the term name in an array
                $term_names[] = ucfirst( str_replace( ['-', '_'],[' ', ' '], $term_slug ) );
            }

            if ( $max_qty > 0 ) {
                $excerpt .= sprintf( '<br/>%s: %s %s',
                    implode(', ', $term_names),
                    $max_qty,
                    __('in stock', 'woocommerce')
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return $excerpt;
}


// Avoid additional content from product short description to be displayed in variation description
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'filter_wc_available_variation_desscription', 10, 3);
function filter_wc_available_variation_desscription( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    $max_qty    = 0 < $variation->get_max_purchase_quantity() ? $variation->get_max_purchase_quantity() : $variation->get_stock_quantity();
    
    if( $max_qty > 0 )
        $data['variation_description'] = get_post_meta( $variation->get_id(), '_variation_description', true );

    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting that code. Unfortunately nothing new is being displayed in my variable product's short descriptions after pasting that code in functions.php and clearing all my caches.

Comment: Hi Loic, thanks for the update. It's partly working, I cannot see the variations before the '':1 in stock'' so basically there are no variables showing before the '' : ''

Comment: Worked great but broke my checkout page with a fatal error pointing towards this line of your code: if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {

Comment: @ChristianBulotaKiteBud Updated, try it now again.

Comment: The stock list information displays twice: once in the short product description (as we wanted) but also again below the variation dropdowns / above the price. I believe it's the woocommerce-variation-description. is there any simple way to hide this so it doesn't display twice on the single product page ? thanks!